# Need some guidance in VUEX and VUEJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, laravel-echo

I have this code block in my vue component

```
    <template>
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="card border-0 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header indigo bg-white border-0 pb-0">Categories</div>

        <div class="card-body pb-1">
            <ul class="list-unstyled pb-1">
                <li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.name" class="pb-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-right indigo-light"></i>
                    &nbsp;<a class="text-secondary text-decoration-none" v-bind:href="'api/categories/'+category.name">
                        {{ category.name }}
                        </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchCategories')
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'categories'
            ])
        }
    }
</script>
```

this fetches the categories from my vuex store and all this is working. What i would like to ask is how would I use laravel echo to change my view? Currently when I add a entry via api (POSTMAN) the entry is created in my table but the view does not update automatically. Pusher is working and I can see the data being posted via the API the state just does not change and the results don't update

Some guidance would be appreciated. Just for reference the fetchCategories code block looks like this:

```
     fetchCategories({commit}) {
      axios.get('/api/categories')
          .then(res => {
              {
                  commit('GET_CATEGORIES', res.data.data)
              }
          }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
          })
  }
```

and my mutation looks like this:

```
    GET_CATEGORIES(state, categories) {
    state.categories = categories
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the state.categories reference change. Then you need to inform Vue the reference changed.

Try using

```
Vue.set(state, 'categories', categories )
```

Comment: when using Vue.set(....) the result is the same. There is no update on the view

Answer (score 0):

What is your state object looks like?

If you don't have categories in your state object, most likely, after you add it to it, categories wont be reactive.

Comment: let state = {
    categories: [],
}
export default state